# How can I improve my downvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I asked a question here in Meta. I wanted to know if I could offer a bounty and ask ELL users to help me improve my downvoted answers or understand why they are wrong. That probably wasn't a good idea (well, it saved me 50 rep, so that is good). One suggestion was to see if anyone here is willing to help.

So, I am hoping if you can take a look at my answers and tell me how I can improve them or why they are incorrect or why they might have been downvoted. I am linking two of them here. Feel free to comment on one or both.

> (a) [turn me to the correct page in the book, in which this topic is located](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/229704/77766)
>
> (b) [a proposal that is discussed in a meeting and a vote is taken on it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/229638/77766)

---

Edit 1:

Possible reasons for the downvote in (a)

> **Identified by Snailcar.**
>
> 1. *"turn to page X"* is commonly used by teachers in classrooms, telling students to turn to that page. We don't usually use that phrase when we ask someone to tell us what page something is on.
> 2. I incorrectly wrote *"**In** which page can I find ...?"* It should be *"**On** which page can I find ..."*
>
> These are now fixed.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about one drive-by downvote. That's probably just someone having a bad day. (That doesn't mean I think you shouldn't be asking for advice here though).